# TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity

I tried to compile my code, but I got the following error:

> TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function,
>   but none was given

my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract memeRegistry {
    string url;
    string name;
    uint timestamp;

    function setmeme(string _url,string _name, uint _timestamp) public{
        url = _url;
        name = _name;
        timestamp = _timestamp;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters and return variables.

Add `memory` after `string`

```
function setmeme(string memory _url, string memory _name, uint _timestamp) public{
```

check here for Solidity 0.5.0. changes https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html

Answer (score 5):

```
//The version I have used is 0.5.2

pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract Inbox{


string public message;

//**Constructor** must be defined using “constructor” keyword

//**In version 0.5.0 or above** it is **mandatory to use “memory” keyword** so as to 
//**explicitly mention the data location**

//you are free to remove the keyword and try for yourself

 constructor (string memory initialMessage) public{
 message=initialMessage;
 }

 function setMessage(string memory newMessage)public{
 message=newMessage;

 }

 function getMessage()public view returns(string memory){
 return message;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me.

- string **memory** firstname

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select a different version of the solidity compiler. `^0.4.25` works for me.

The version of the solidity compiler has to be set both on the file and in the compile tab on remix(it is a drop-down menu).

Comment: if i use a different compiler its giving me a SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.0+

Comment: You have to change the compiler version both on the file and also from remix. It is a drop-down menu on the compile tab. I have selected this: `0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1` and it had no problem with your code.

Comment: changed both on the file and compiler and its now working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the return parameters explicitly memory:

Thus,

```
function setmeme(string _url,string _name, uint _timestamp) public
```

Becomes

```
function setmeme(string memory _url, string memory _name, uint _timestamp) public{
```